# Reduce recursively pushing only once

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, ecmascript-2016

I am trying to run a reduce method recursively on an array of objects.

I start with an string and push the object that matches that string then I see what object that entry `ReportsTo`, once I get that object I push it and kepp on checking recursively who that object `ReportsTo` next till it reaches the max `Rank` in this case of 3.

But it does not push beyond the first one.

```js
const data = [
  {
    Name: 'Peter',
    ReportsTo: '',
    Rank: 1
  },
  {
    Name: 'Tom',
    ReportsTo: 'Peter',
    Rank: 2
  },
  {
    Name: 'Maria',
    ReportsTo: 'Tom',
    Rank: 3
  },
  {
    Name: 'John',
    ReportsTo: 'Peter',
    Rank: 3
  },
  {
    Name: 'Fiona',
    ReportsTo: 'Maria',
    Rank: 4
  }
]

const findManager = (person) => data.reduce((total, current) => {
  if (current.Name === person) {
    total.push(current)
    if (current.Rank > 2) {
      findManager(current.ReportsTo)
    }
  }  
  
  return total
}, [])

console.log(findManager('Fiona'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The desire output will be all the objects that are lower than 3 and that manage in this case `Fiona`

```
[ 
  { Name: 'Fiona', ReportsTo: 'Maria', Rank: 4 },
  { Name: 'Maria', ReportsTo: 'Tom', Rank: 3 },
  { Name: 'Tom', ReportsTo: 'Peter', Rank: 2 }
]
```

Comment: Why does `findManager()` return something (`return total`) when you're not interested in that value (`if (...) { findManager(...) }`)?

Comment: But I am interested in returning the next one as long as the `Rank` is higher than 3, I have to return the total at some point on a reduce right?

Comment: Then... Why don't you return the total?

Comment: I think according to the responses that I am using the wrong function for what I need, but out of curiosity what do mean just return the total?, I am.

Comment: Not in the `if ( ... )` block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really see the point in using `reduce` here. `reduce` is intended to provide some combined result from a series of values, but you are just looking for one value (and using a side-effect to accomplish it).

I think this is a better approach:

```js
const findManagers = (name) => {
    const foundPerson = data.find(({ Name }) => Name === name);
    
    return foundPerson.Rank > 2
        ? [foundPerson, ...findManagers(foundPerson.ReportsTo)]
        : [foundPerson];
};

const data = [
  {
    Name: 'Peter',
    ReportsTo: '',
    Rank: 1
  },
  {
    Name: 'Tom',
    ReportsTo: 'Peter',
    Rank: 2
  },
  {
    Name: 'Maria',
    ReportsTo: 'Tom',
    Rank: 3
  },
  {
    Name: 'John',
    ReportsTo: 'Peter',
    Rank: 3
  },
  {
    Name: 'Fiona',
    ReportsTo: 'Maria',
    Rank: 4
  }
]

console.log(findManagers('Fiona'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, very similar to @CertainPerformance but I really like the ternary

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `.reduce` is the appropriate tool here, since you're trying to find *just one* item in the array inside a given iteration through the array. Either use `.find` or a plain loop. Then you need to use the result of the recursive call - one way to approach this would be to have a second parameter, the array of results, that gets passed around and pushed to:

```js
const data=[{Name:"Peter",ReportsTo:"",Rank:1},{Name:"Tom",ReportsTo:"Peter",Rank:2},{Name:"Maria",ReportsTo:"Tom",Rank:3},{Name:"John",ReportsTo:"Peter",Rank:3},{Name:"Fiona",ReportsTo:"Maria",Rank:4}];

const findManagers = (name, results = []) => {
  const person = data.find(p => p.Name === name);
  results.push(person);
  if (person.Rank > 2) {
    findManagers(person.ReportsTo, results)
  }
  return results;
};
console.log(findManagers('Fiona'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I had something very similar, I just tried to use reduce to get that array returned, but this does just that, thanks!